# Access VBA Send Mail with Attachement (QueryDef) into a loop

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

**What are you trying to accomplish?**

I'm trying to create for each rs a mail item. This mail item should have a temporary query as attachement. Via TransferSpreadSheet I load my temporary Query into Folder.

**Paste the part of the code that shows the problem.**

Problem is the query def. It shows me always the same data in attachement, not the data for each rs. I suggest that I have to include the query def into my loop, but therefore I need your help.

```
Sub ExcelExportuSenden()

Dim day As Integer
day = Weekday(Date, vbSunday)
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim toMulti, waarde As String
Dim mItem As Outlook.MailItem  ' An Outlook Mail item
Dim dbs As Database
Dim qdfTemp As QueryDef
Dim qdfNew As QueryDef
Dim originalSql As String
Dim Identified_name As Recordset
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set mItem = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Dim rs  As Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Mailversand")  'Get name for the email distro

If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF
        With mItem
            Set mItem = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
            toMulti = rs![email]
            waarde = toMulti
            For Each qdf In dbs.QueryDefs
                If qdf.Name = "Anfrage_zur_Ausschreibung" Then
                   dbs.QueryDefs.Delete "Anfrage_zur_Ausschreibung"
                   Exit For
                End If
            Next

            Set qdfTemp = dbs.CreateQueryDef("Anfrage_zur_Ausschreibung")
            With dbs
               'Run query on selected Name product manager
                qdfTemp.SQL = "SELECT * FROM [Filter_Ausschreibung_original] WHERE [Lieferant] = '" & rs![Lieferant] & "'"
                DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Anfrage_zur_Ausschreibung", "Q:\LU\Test\Anfrage_zur_Ausschreibung.xlsx", True

            End With

        .To = toMulti
        MsgBox toMulti
        .Subject = "Anfrage zu Ausschreibung"
        .HTMLBody = "Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren"
        .Display
        .Attachments.Add ("Q:\LU\Test\Anfrage_zur_Ausschreibung.xlsx")

    End With

       rs.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
    MsgBox "No email address!"
End If
olApp.Quit
Set olApp = Nothing
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

**What do you expect the result to be?**
Each rs should have a different attachement. The part which belongs to "Lieferant".

**What is the actual result you get? (Please include any errors.)**
I only got one attachement, and this is always with the same content.

**UPDATE**
I'm trying to work with Parfait's solution. Problem now is an error on following part:

```
'Export temp table to Excel
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
          "Anfrage_zur_Ausschreibung_TEMP", _
          "Q:\LU\_Rothenhöfer\Test\Anfrage_zur_Ausschreibung_TEMP.xlsx", True
```

[image]

Full code is now:

```
Sub ExcelExportuSenden()

Dim day As Integer
day = Weekday(Date, vbSunday)
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim toMulti, waarde As String
Dim mItem As Outlook.MailItem  ' An Outlook Mail item
Dim dbs As Database
Dim qdfTemp As QueryDef
Dim qdfNew As QueryDef
Dim originalSql As String
Dim Identified_name As Recordset
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set mItem = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Dim rs  As Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Mailversand")  'Get name for the email distro

If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rs.MoveFirst

Do Until rs.EOF
    With mItem
        Set mItem = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        toMulti = rs![email]
        waarde = toMulti

        Set qdfTemp = dbs.CreateQueryDef("Anfrage_zur_Ausschreibung")
        qdfTemp.SQL = "PARAMETERS LieferantParam Text ( 255 ); " & _
                      "SELECT * INTO Anfrage_zur_Ausschreibung_TEMP " & _
                      "From Filter_Ausschreibung_original " & _
                      "WHERE [Lieferant] = rs![Lieferant]"

        Set qdfTemp = Nothing

        'Export temp table to Excel
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
              "Anfrage_zur_Ausschreibung_TEMP", _
              "Q:\LU\Test\Anfrage_zur_Ausschreibung.xlsx", True

        .To = toMulti
        MsgBox toMulti
        .Subject = "Anfrage zu Ausschreibung"
        .HTMLBody = "Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren"
        .Display
        .Attachments.Add ("Q:\LU\Test\Anfrage_zur_Ausschreibung.xlsx")
    End With
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
Else
    MsgBox "No email address!"
End If
olApp.Quit
Set olApp = Nothing
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you remove the "Data" from your DoCmd, as this field is only applicable for importing and not exporting...

Comment: Yes, what @Xabier says is correct. Your parameter 'DATA' is for the 'Range' and the documentation states:  "...When you export to a spreadsheet, you must leave this argument blank. If you enter a range, the export will fail."  Also, I don't see where you issue the ".Send"?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn he is using the .Display instead of .Send, so you can preview before sending...

Comment: Yes the .Display show me each mail in a preview, but only with the same attachement...

Comment: @Xabier I don't understand what you mean with "remove the Date from you DoCmd". Could you explain it? Many thanks (i am a beginner in vba)

Comment: @DR1989 the last word on the line that begins with DoCmd, remove the , "Data", (not date), remove the comma that comes before it as well too.

Comment: Ugh! My bad ... too set in my ways expecting the last action to be the deal maker!

Comment: I removed it. But it is still attach a query with the same content.

Comment: To clearify my problem. the query def should do a query into the loop for each "Lieferant" (its the german word for supplier). Each supplier have different products. My query should only show the productswhich belongs to the supplier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply release your *qTemp* after you update its SQL, otherwise no changes are propagated:

```
' UPDATE QUERY
Set qdfTemp = dbs.CreateQueryDef("Anfrage_zur_Ausschreibung")
qdfTemp.SQL = "<SQL Query>"
Set qdfTemp = Nothing                 ' RELEASES QUERYDEF

' EXPORT QUERY TO EXCEL
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport ...
```

However, reconsider this approach of deleting and re-creating queries by concatenating VBA variables to SQL statement. Consider [parameterization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193967.aspx) for cleaner, maintainable, slightly efficient code that iteratively builds a temp table for excel export.

**SQL** *(save as a permanent make-table action query with `PARAMETERS` clause)*

```sql
PARAMETERS LieferantParam TEXT;
SELECT * INTO Anfrage_zur_Ausschreibung_TEMP
FROM [Filter_Ausschreibung_original] 
WHERE [Lieferant] = [LieferantParam];
```

**VBA** *(loop section only running above action by current parameter)*

```
Do Until rs.EOF    
    With mItem
        Set mItem = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        toMulti = rs![email]
        waarde = toMulti

        'Retrieve make-table query and bind parameter to name product manager
        Set qdfTemp = dbs.QueryDef("Anfrage_zur_Ausschreibung_QUERY")
        qdfTemp![LieferantParam] = rs![Lieferant]
        qdfTemp.Execute, dbFailOnError

        'Export temp table to Excel   
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
              "Anfrage_zur_Ausschreibung_TEMP", _
              "Q:\LU\Test\Anfrage_zur_Ausschreibung.xlsx", True

        .To = toMulti
        MsgBox toMulti
        .Subject = "Anfrage zu Ausschreibung"
        .HTMLBody = "Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren"
        .Display
        .Attachments.Add ("Q:\LU\Test\Anfrage_zur_Ausschreibung.xlsx")    
    End With    
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I guess this is the right way, but I'm trying to use it and got an error (see in my update above)

Comment: Please translate error message as this an English site. And your implementation is definitely not the same as my approach. You do not parameterize at all but interpoate the `rs![Lieferant]` directly into SQL string which is an unrecognized value. Plus I advised to save the query as a stored query not rebuilt each time. All you do in VBA is bind value to parameter placeholder.

Comment: You can use your approach but then remove needless `PARAMETERS` clause and then concatenate `rs![Lieferant]` to string in `WHERE` expression with quote wrappers like you originally did.

Comment: Now it works, I thought Anfrage_zur_Ausschreibung_QUERY is query and Anfrage_zur_Ausschreibung_Temp is another query. Sorry for my misunderstanding and many thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Yes, *_Query* is a special action not `SELECT` query (i.e., [make-table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-make-table-query-96424f9e-82fd-411e-aca4-e21ad0a94f1b)), and *_Temp* is a temp table. I changed your approach in this manner to allow for parameterization. Using a stored query for export, you cannot save a query with binded parameter value except virtually at runtime unless exporting DAO recordsets via VBA to Excel.